# How to remove all portrait pictures from a document

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on OCRing a document image. I want to detect all pictures and remove from the document image. I want to retain tables in the document image. Once I detect pictures I will remove and then want to OCR. I tried to find contour tried to detect all the bigger areas. unfortunately it detects tables also. Also how to remove the objects keeping other data in the doc image. I am using opencv and python

[image: This is my document Image]

Here's my code

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('block2.jpg' , 0)
mask = np.ones(img.shape[:2], dtype="uint8") * 255


ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)
contours, sd = cv2.findContours(thresh1,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

areacontainer = []

for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    areacontainer.append(area)

avgArea = sum(areacontainer)/len(areacontainer)

    [enter code here][1]

for c in contours:# average area heuristics
    if cv2.contourArea(c)>6*avgArea:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, 0, -1)

binary = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask) # subtracting
cv2.imwrite("bin.jpg" , binary)
cv2.imwrite("mask.jpg" , mask)
```

Comment: What is a *"document image"* please? You are also supposed to show the code you have tried and provide all materials so that folks can run your code and correct/improve it. See **Minimum Complete Verifiable Example** https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added the input image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach:

- Convert image to grayscale and Gaussian blur
- Perform canny edge detection
- Perform morphological operations to smooth image
- Find contours and filter using a minimum/maximum threshold area
- Remove portrait images

---

Here's the detected portraits highlighted in green

[image]

Now that we have the bounding box ROIs, we can effectively remove the pictures by filling them in with white. Here's the result

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
canny = cv2.Canny(blur, 120, 255, 1)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(canny, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)

cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 15000 and area < 35000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255,255,255), -1)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thank you  nathancy . I have another extended question . I have a mask image which has my ROI . What would be the best to pick the co ordinates ?

Comment: What do you mean pick the coordinates??