# How can i classify only-text image(petition, invoice, page of a book) and a normal image(cat,person ) as a 2 different type?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-classification

I don't think detecting text on image does work because normal images can have text on them too(like traffic sign). Is there a way to do this? I couldn't come up with an answer.

Comment: check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57931506/11353623

Comment: I think i got misunderstood sir. I meant to classify this two types, not extract from each other. My bad.

Comment: Text images are often characterised by a) having only 2 main colours - a background and a text colour, b) having horizontal rows of foreground colour, c) having many small, similarly sized components (letters) when split into *"connected components"*, or *"contours"*.